# React setState only re-renders on second call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a problem where `setState` only re-renders the component on the **second setState**, although set state is called, and setState is being given a copy (new reference) to the object that is being mutated. Set state initial value seems to also be correctly setup

The state is basically an object where each key / value is a setting, and a true/false toggle.

The code follows:

```tsx
interface optionInterface {
  label: string
  labelTx?: TextProps["tx"]
  value: string
}

export interface MultiToggleProps {
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>
  options: optionInterface[]
  singleChoice?: boolean
  onChange?: (value: any) => void
}

export const MultiToggle = observer(function MultiToggle(props: MultiToggleProps) {
  const { style, options, singleChoice, onChange} = props
  const $styles = [$container, style]
  const [selectionState, setSelectionState] = React.useState(
      options.reduce((acc, option) => {
        acc[option.value] = false
        return acc
      }, {})
  )

  const toggleSelected = (key: string) => {
    const newSelectionState = {...selectionState}

    if (singleChoice) {
      // reset all choices
      Object.keys(newSelectionState).forEach((k) => {
        newSelectionState[k] = false
      })
    }
    // flip the changed choice
    newSelectionState[key] = !!!newSelectionState[key]
    setSelectionState(newSelectionState)
    onChange(newSelectionState)
  }

  return (
    <View style={$styles}>
      {options.map((option, index) => {
        return (
          <View key={index} style={$toggleItem} >
            <Toggle 
              variant="radio"
              value={selectionState[option.value]}
              key={index} label={option.label} labelTx={option.labelTx} onValueChange={() =>
                toggleSelected(option.value)
              }
              />
          </View>
        )
      })}
    </View>
  )
})
```

I've tried to move the initialisations of the state to useEffect, or just initialise the state with an empty object with no luck. I still have to click 2x on the toggle on the first render for it to work (subsequent setStates work correctly). It is not the Toggle logic, since when I render the state as a JSON string, it displays the same behaviour as the toggle component. `toggleSelected` is called correctly, and with the correct values, and does call `setState`.

Comment: What specific debugging observation are you making to reach the conclusion that the state update is not triggering a re-render?  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which gives a live demonstration of this and indicate the observation you're making in that example?

Comment: @David thanks for taking the time. In fact I can NOT reproduce this in React (my original problem is in React native)... In my original project it takes 2 clicks to toggle one of the toggles on the first render. I've made a console.log of the new state object, and I'm rendering the JSON of the sate in the component as a debug.

Although I get a console log of the new state correctly, the JSON string of the new state does not update to the output of the console.log.

Here's a (working?) version.
https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-greider-ygw7qy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about +5h of debugging, I realised that I was wrongly passing the value of the component to the `key` prop of `MultiToggle` by mistake (probably a copy-pasta)

```
<Controller
   render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
            //         very wrong
            //            vvvv
       <MultiToggle key={value} singleChoice options={interruptionReasonOptions} onChange={value => onChange(value)} />
    )
/>
```

Because the key changed when I first changed the value, it triggered a re-render - but with a brand new initial state. However that did not happen on subsequent state changes, maybe because the reference to the form-hook `value` stayed the same.

In short, lesson learned: when debugging rendering, always start with the basics of `key`. Thanks [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david) for the help!